# How can I generate a random tuple of ints using a lambda function in Python?

Tags: lambda

I need to generate a random tuple of ints,  p = (i,j)

how can I complete this function

random_tuple = lambda i,j:

Comment: Why use a lambda here? What are `i` and `j` supposed to do?

Comment: i and j are supposed to be coordinates to a specific pixel in an image. I need to make a function out of them so that I can call it later and it would generate a point with coordinates (i,j)